# XCode can't find library which is in embedded framework

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift-package-manager

I'm getting the following error from XCode over and over:

```
ld: library not found for -lMyLib for architecture arm64
```

The problem is that that lib is actually a subtarget of an embedded framework to the main project.

So my project had Embedded(+ Linked) framework and that framework has sub-target (generated with SPM) which is MyLib.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `MyLib` reference manually to the main project, add this library into Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.